# Datalog: Why does (X==False) & (Y==not(X)) not evaluate?

Tags: python, datalog, pydatalog

I'm using pyDatalog (in Python 2.7). Using an arithmetic function like `+`, I can refer to an earlier bound variable:

```
>>> (X==1) & (Y==X+1)
[(1, 2)]
```

But I cannot use the boolean `not` operator the same way:

```
>>> not(False)
True
>>> (X==False) & (Y==not(X))
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    (X==False) & (Y==not(X))
                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
```

Comment: `not` is a keyword, *not* a function. So this should be `Y == not X`, but that will probably not solve the matter.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Your code raises the same syntax error. People don't get what is going on here...

Answer (score 1):

You could use a custom resolver :

```
from pyDatalog import pyDatalog

@pyDatalog.predicate()
def not_2(X,Y):
    if X.is_const():
        yield (X.id, not(X.id))
    elif Y.is_const():
        yield (not(Y.id), Y.id)

@pyDatalog.program()
def _():
    print ((X==False) & (not_(X,Y)))
```

Comment: What black magic is this?

You define `not_2` but then you call `not`. The code runs, but then when I try to evaluate `(X==False) & (not_2(X,Y))` by itself in the REPL I get `name 'not' is not defined`. If I use `not_2` instead, I get an `AttributeError: 'generator' object has no attribute 'literals'`.

Reading the code, it only looks like it should work if X or Y is a constant. To test that, I tried replacing the last line with `print ((X==False) & (not_(X,Y)) & (not_(Y,Z)))`. But that prints exactly the same output, as if it's ignoring Z.

Comment: I'm using a custom predicate resolvers for not_.  See Advanced Topics on pyDatalog site.

Answer (score -1):

it is operator precedence in Python

```
(Y == (not(X))
```

or

```
(Y == not X)
```

Comment: This is not even the issue

Comment: @JBernardo changed

Comment: When I evaluate `(X==False) & (Y==(not(X)))` I get `[(False, False)]`.